# Which line in the code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, breakpoints

Is there any way to get which line of the code is running?

E.g. in some method I ran another programm and I'm waiting to ending. Now I want to know which line called this program without using breakpoints

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you're asking. "which line caused" *what?* Are you trying to understand where a crash/exception happened? (In which case look at the stack trace: if you have full debug symbols that'll give you the line number.)

Comment: Look at this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hit the "pause" button in the debugger, navigate to the right thread if necessary, and look at the stack, you'll see where you are. If that's not what you're looking for, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just Ctrl-Break to pause the debugger; if you didn't even start in the debugger, you can 'Attach Process', and do the same.

Note that line number information will be present only if compiled with debug information (usually on only for Debug build configurations)